# Is there any steps to configure android-cts latest version 13 on docker?

Tags: docker, cts, android-cts

Android CTS Failed with exception [ANDROID_PARTNER_SERVER_ERROR|500505|DEPENDENCY_ISSUE] in docker container.

Able to run the same cts on linux PC, but not from docker container.

- Linux PC is Ubuntu 20.04
- Configured android-cts[Android Compatibility Test Suite 13_r2 (9265165)]
  on ubuntu docker image with all the basic requirement like java[jdk 11], sdk[adb[1.0.41],aapt] etc.
- container network configuration is same as host [ used --network=host] with same proxy.
- Executed [export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS='-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true'] as running behind firewall.
- To start the container: docker run -it --network host -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ubuntu:20.04

Failed with exception
[ANDROID_PARTNER_SERVER_ERROR|500505|DEPENDENCY_ISSUE].
`Traceback: 01-18 07:50:43 E/TestInvocation: Trying to access android partner remote server over internet but failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out) com.android.tradefed.targetprep.TargetSetupError[**ANDROID_PARTNER_SERVER_ERROR|500505|DEPENDENCY_ISSUE**]: Trying to access android partner remote server over internet but failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out) at com.android.compatibility.common.tradefed.targetprep.DynamicConfigPusher.resolveUrl(DynamicConfigPusher.java:282) at com.android.compatibility.common.tradefed.targetprep.DynamicConfigPusher.setUp(DynamicConfigPusher.java:155) at com.android.tradefed.invoker.InvocationExecution.runPreparationOnDevice(InvocationExecution.java:534) at com.android.tradefed.invoker.InvocationExecution.runPreparersSetup(InvocationExecution.java:436) at com.android.tradefed.invoker.InvocationExecution.doSetup(InvocationExecution.java:296) at com.android.tradefed.invoker.TestInvocation.prepareAndRun(TestInvocation.java:583) at com.android.tradefed.invoker.TestInvocation.performInvocation(TestInvocation.java:273) at com.android.tradefed.invoker.TestInvocation.invoke(TestInvocation.java:1308) at com.android.tradefed.command.CommandScheduler$InvocationThread.run(CommandScheduler.java:639) Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out) at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399) at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242) at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224) at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:299) at java.base/sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173) at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:182) at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474) at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569) at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:266) at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:373) at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:203) at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1187) at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081) at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:189) at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1592) at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520) at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250) at java.base/java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1165) at com.android.compatibility.common.tradefed.targetprep.DynamicConfigPusher.resolveUrl(DynamicConfigPusher.java:279) ... 8 more 01-18 07:50:43 I/CommandInterrupter: Interrupt blocked`
please let me know, if am missing anything.

Comment: From logs, container failed to establish internet connection